# How should my execl command look in order for it to display "CPU info" in linux command window

Tags: c, execl

I am writing code in C in a Linux terminal trying to display CPU info when the command is run.

```
execl ( "/bin/lscpu","lscpu",(char*)0);
```

I have tried everything and can't seem to find the answer that works. This command is giving me a blank and not sure how my `execl` command should look here.

Comment: Does your code continue after the call to to `execl`? If so, you should check `errno`

Comment: no, my code is supposed to end after displaying the information in the terminal

Comment: Yes, *supposed to*. But *does it*?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: And have you checked `errno`? What happens when you put the line `perror("exec");` below that line?

Comment: It says "No such file or directory". it makes more sense now. Thanks but do you know what changes I can make to my execl command to get the cpuinfo?

Comment: Try typing `which lscpu` in your terminal. It'll show you where it is (or not in case you don't have it)

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I'm very new to linux and don't understand 1 thing if I write "lscpu" it displays the information that I need but when I tried "which lscpu" it is saying no file or directory.v Which makes sense but don't understand why lscpu is working there in the first place?

Comment: It's probably `/usr/bin/lscpu` instead of `/bin/lscpu`

Comment: Your shell searches your path (PATH environment variable) to find commands you enter such as lscpu.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thank you so much. I still don't understand few things about it but I'll eventually figure them out. Thanks I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Check that the specified path to lscpu is correct,

```
ls -altr /bin/lscpu
```

Where is lscpu located?

```
which lscpu
ls -altr /bin/lscpu /usr/bin/lscpu
```

Inspect the error returned (the following works),

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int err;
    err = execl( "/bin/lscpu","lscpu",(char*)0 );
    if( err != 0 ) {
        printf("errno=%d: %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

If you replace the pathname (append an 'X'), you will get an error,

```
err = execl( "/bin/lscpuX","lscpu",(char*)0 );
```

Comment: You don't actually have to check the return value. `execl` never returns unless there is an error.

Comment: Except that OP had an error, and was blind to the error.

Comment: Yes, and *if* `execl` returns you should check errors. But it doesn't matter *what* `execl` returns.